# Can we move the discussiony comments from "What RPGs emphasize Roleplaying?" to meta?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The comments have gotten out of control. The standard action when this happens on a SO site, is to move the comments to a meta thread.

So ya, can we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have instead moved the "[What is roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/what-exactly-is-roleplaying-the-action-not-the-hobby-closed)" question to meta and purged comments on the "[What RPGs emphasize roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/what-rpgs-emphasize-roleplaying)" question.

Comment: Thanks! and some extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, feel free to create a meta question for any or all of the comments you think needs discussion.

Comment: Thats usually a moderator task (deleting comments)

Comment: I can make a thread, but I sure can't move 'em

Comment: And I can't figure out how to move 'em.  I can delete them all...